# Isn't the concept of basis kind of circular?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

If $v$ is an element of a vector space $V$ and for example $\mathcal{B}=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a basis of $V$, then, at least, there should be another basis for $V$ in which the vectors of $\mathcal{B}$ can be expressed, but at the same time, the vectors of this other basis must also be expressed using $\mathcal{B}$'s vectors.

Why is there no problem here?

Comment: It seems you think of elements in a vector space in terms of  coordinates w.r.t. a basis, which is wrong; vectors exist by themselves, and bases are a *tool* to make computations.

Comment: @Bernard thank you, that was it.

Comment: Vector *spaces* have basis.  Actually individual vectors do not. $\mathcal{B}=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ can be a basis for the vector *space* that $V$ is in (in which case $V = \alpha e_1 + \beta e_2 +\gamma e_3$) but $\mathcal B$ being a basis for a vector $V$ just doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is more linear than circular.

Comment: @fleablood I just noticed missing information and I uncapped the element, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no problem, since a vector does **not** need a basis to be expressed. Take, for instance, the vector space $V$ of all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb R$. And now conside the map $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=e^x$. It belongs to $V$, right? But I had no need of a basis of $V$ in order to express it.

Comment: What about the vector space $\mathbb{R^2}$? Don't we use $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ as a basis for it and those same vectors can be expressed in another basis whose vectors can also be expressed in the afore mentioned basis?

Comment: @Luyw Expressing a vector in terms of a basis means specifying suitable coefficients. It can be done no matter which basis you choose. The advantage of the one you mentioned is the coefficients end up being the coordinates in the tuples, viz. $(x,\,y)=x(1,\,0)+y(0,\,1)$.

Comment: okay no I got this, thank you.